# Test if a cookie exist with it name in a variable

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies

I'd like to test if a cookie exists, pretty basic, I know, but something doesn't want to work well. So, here is the pieces of code that are related:

```
<?php $quesID = the_ID()."GCQuestion";
if(isset($_COOKIE[$quesID])){
  ...
}
```

The test always fails, even when the cookie's name match the generated variable. Weird part is when I try to type the variable name by hand `if(isset($_COOKIE["94GCQuestion"]))`, it works.

Question is : can we use a variable as a name for `$_COOKIE` ?

Comment: are you sure that `the_ID` is returning the correct thing?

Comment: Yes, I tested by doing an `echo $quesID` and I correctly have `94GCQuestion`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using Wordpress,

> [**`the_ID()`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_ID): Displays the numeric ID of the current post. This tag must be within The Loop.

[`the_ID()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_ID) is a template function and it will just print the ID, it doesn't return it.

To return the ID, use [**`get_the_ID()`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_ID) instead.

```
<?php $quesID = get_the_ID()."GCQuestion";
if(isset($_COOKIE[$quesID])){
  ...
}
```